# How to provide feature files to karate from outisde the JAR file?

Tags: java, karate

I'm new to Karate and I'm trying to use it to test an API written in nodeJS.

Using this github project - https://github.com/thirdy/karate-fat-test-jar - I was able to get a single karate.jar file which had all dependencies built-in. However, to my surprise even the `*.feature` files were part of the JAR file.

Is there any way to keep the karate JAR file separate and the feature files separate? Ultimately I want to build the karate JAR file only once in my build pipeline (and cache it), and keep using the JAR file with different feature files for every build. Is this possible? How?

Comment: oh, if you are new to java and maven - the rule is anything under `src/main` is in the JAR - so you may need to understand (or ask another question) on maven basics